# Linked Class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

As everyone knows: It's possbile to create linkes lists with C / C++ in order to make a program dynamical.
But now, I'm programming a "linked Class" in c++.
My Parent-Class "GAME" should have a variable number of Elements. And each Element is a class.
So I programmed this:

```
class GAME : public LEVEL
{  private:
     ELEMENT *startPointer;
   public:
     GAME()
     {    startPointer=NULL;
     }
     initGame()
     {    p=aStartPointer;
          while(p!=NULL);//This loop is based on a linked list, so its dynamic
          {   startPointer=new ELEMENT(startPointer);
              p=p->next;
          }
     }
}


class ELEMENT
{   private:
        ELEMENT *next;
    public:
        ELEMENT(ELEMENT* nextPointer)
        {    next=nextPointer;
        }
}
```

My Problem: I never heard about a linked class before, and I'm not sure if I should use it.
Does professional programmers use such methods (and is it usefull?), or are there better Methods to do this?

Comment: Professional programmers use the standard containers, like `std::vector` and `std::list`. Professional programmers do not write their own linked-list implementations, at least not if they want to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > are there better Methods to do this?

Yes. Here is one:

```
class GAME : public LEVEL
{  private:
     std::vector<ELEMENT> elements;
   ...
};
```

Use the standard library containers:

- Generally, use `std::vector<>`.
- If you need uniqueness, use `std::set<>`
- If you need to associate elements with keys, use `std::map<>`
- If you need to insert or delete items from the container very often or very quickly, use `std::list<>` or `std::set<>`
- There are other considerations. Consult a good book to learn how to effectively use standard containers.

Comment: As a general rule, if you think you should use `std::list<>`, reconsider.

Comment: @Yakk +1: I remember a talk about some MSVC STL implementation performance analysis; they found that due to locality of reference, even in situations where list theoretically scales better than vector, it is surprising how absurdly far you have to push for list to actually start 'returning on investment'.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is create a container that can contain *different types* of object instances (ie, a non-homogeneous container), there're several approaches (which generally involve homogenizing the container).  You can either set up a common base clase so that you can store handles-to-base.  Another option is discriminated unions.

As the other posts mention, the container itself should probably be an STL container, unless you have a really good reason to use something else (and even then, the 'more standard', the better; homebrew is not a good idea unless it is for educational purposes only).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to implement a linked list under a different name. A better design would be to use a list or vector as a member of your class to store the `ELEMENTS` instead of having it be the basic functionality of the `GAME` class.

This allows you to have a separation between container-like object and your application classes.